# Changing Apple ID on Macbook to match ID on iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, ipad, apple-id

My 13” Mac has a different Apple ID than my iPad and iPhone. I’d like to change the Apple ID on my mac so I can utilize apps properly.

Comment: Add another user account, that way you have both ID’s

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  You should be able to log out of the Mac and log back in with the same Apple ID as your iPhone & iPad.  What have you tried?

Comment: What does "utilize apps properly" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Sign out of the old Apple ID on the mac, knowing that you need to keep all the content there. Apps will lose permissions / update while you switch in the proper Apple ID.

Sign in with the proper AppleID so you can share all the data and other apps. They when you have an update, sign back in with the original AppleID (only if you want) to allow updates to the previously purchased apps, but not lose the data syncing from iCloud on the same account on both platforms.

Comment: Isn't there a way to transfer purchases from one ID to another?  For Photos, Music, and e-books you didn't purchase from Apple, you can just drag them out of their apps to Desktop and import them again on the new ID.

Comment: Not that I’ve seen @WGroleau - if the accounts can be part of a family, some purchases can be shared, though.

Comment: I looked a bit and found https://www.ubackup.com/phone-backup/transfer-purchases-to-new-apple-id.html … but I'm not sure I would trust it.